# ASP.Net MVC: Access validation error messages in the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to access validation error messages in the controller. I'm not finding them anywhere in ModelState.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterating over ModelState is used for this purpose. 
Something along these lines:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var item in ModelState)
    {
        string key = item.Key;
        var errors = item.Value.Errors;

        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            result.Append(key + " " + error.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }

    TempData["Errors"] = result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is old but I just stumbled into it looking for something else and will leave it here - perhaps someone could find it useful:

```
var err = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);

foreach(var y in err)
{
    // add each to your list of strings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate an object in the controller using the [Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx)

Comment: I don't need to validate in the controller -- that's already being done by the MVC framework -- I just want to access the error messages generated by the framework's validation process in the controller rather than the view. I want to place the messages into the master view via TempData